# Factorial number

Tags: functions, factorial

Can anybody explain how
$$
(k+2)(k+1)!-1 = (k+2)!-1
$$
also how
$$
(k+1)!-1+(k+1)(k+1)! = [1+(k+1)](k+1)!-1
$$
my book show this example but i can't understand how.
I also try google it but cannot write it in word, sad

Comment: yep, check and check again, i also try reverse it but less the       -(k+1),headache o, not understand

Comment: What is the book?

Comment: Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics by Ralph P. Grimaldi. Btw, i figure out it from the advise given below, thank all of u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general recursive definition of factorial is 
$$0!=1$$
$$(n+1)!=(n+1)\cdot n!\quad\text{for }n\ge0$$
Thus especially
$$(k+2)!=(k+2)\cdot (k+1)!$$
Also, by distributivity
$$(k+1)!+(k+1)\cdot(k+1)!=(1+k+1)(k+1)!=(k+2)(k+1)!=(k+2)!$$

Comment: thx, i take my time to digest this

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Use $k! = k(k-1)!$. The second one is just factoring the right terms out.

Comment: thx, try my best to understand

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume you mean $(k+1)! \times (k+2) - 1 = (k+2)! - 1.$

To see that they are, just apply the definition of factorial. For example: $3! = 1 \times 2 \times 3.$ It follows that $[3!] \times 4 = [1 \times 2 \times 3] \times 4 = 4!$. In general:

$$(k+1)! \times (k+2) = [1 \times 2 \times \cdots \times k \times (k+1)] \times (k+2) = (k+2)!$$

If $(k+1)! \times (k+2) = (k+2)!$ then $(k+1)! \times (k+2) -1 = (k+2)!-1.$

For your second question, we can add $1$ to both sides to give

$$(k+1)!+(k+1)\times (k+1)! = [1+(k+1)](k+1)!$$

There is a common factor of $(k+1)!$ on the left and so:

$$(k+1)![1+(k+1)] = [1+(k+1)](k+1)!$$

Done...

Comment: thx, i getting the big picture